# prepared statement in php is returning 0 rows

Tags: php

I have a table with only one row called users in my database with email and mobile_number as it's columns.My row has that mobile_number column value as 9866163987.When I am trying to select this mobile number value my prepared statement is returning 0 rows.Here is my code.

```
if($this->checkExists("email",$_POST["registerEmail"]))
{
    --some code--
}
if($this->checkExists("mobile_number",$_POST["registerMobileNumber"]))
{
     --some code--
}
private function checkExists($field,$value)
{
    include("includes/connection.php");
    $sql = "SELECT $field FROM users WHERE $field=:value";      
    $prepare = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $prepare->bindParam(":value",$value,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    try
    {
        $prepare->execute();
    }       
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {           
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
    $count = count($prepare->fetchAll());
    echo $count."<br />";
    if($count == 1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

For email it is working fine and returning one row,but for mobile_number it is returning 0 rows?what to do?

Comment: Check the actual value of `$value` to see if the input makes sense. Maybe the value was posted incorrectly. Or it's posted fine, but it just happens to be a number that doesn't match anything in the database.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.i checked my database.it is exactly what you said.mismatching of values.but the problem is i am inserting 9866163987,but in the database some other value 2147483647 is being inserted.what to do???

Comment: Are you representing the mobile number as an int?  Sounds like you're running into an integer overflow problem.  Try changing the column to a CHAR(10).  The correct value you be persisted at that point.

Comment: What type is the field in the table? You might be overflowing the field. \2147483647 is the largest value that can be stored in a signed 32-bit integer.

Comment: Your column in your table isn't a string...

Answer (score 0):

Your interger is being truncated because it exceed the 32 bit limit of an int. (as @Mike Stotts said in the comments)

see [What is the size of column of int(11) in mysql in bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634104/what-is-the-size-of-column-of-int11-in-mysql-in-bytes)

You could use a string instead or use something bigger like bigint.

Note: if you plan on using bigint, you should consider adding store_result(); before your bind_result to prevent memory exhaustion:
See: [PHP mysql_stmt::fetch() gives PHP Fatal error memory exhausted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509531/php-mysql-stmtfetch-gives-php-fatal-error-memory-exhausted)